# Is a field extension $L/K$ finite if and only if $L$ is a finitely-generated $K$-algebra?

Tags: commutative-algebra

I recently started learning commutative algebra from Atiyah-MacDonald.

This means that for the next few months, I'll be posting some (mostly silly) questions to check my understanding.  (Thank you all in advance for your patience.)

> **My understanding:** Let $L/K$ be a field extension.  Then the following are equivalent:
>
> (1) $L$ is a finitely-generated $K$-algebra
>
> (2) $L/K$ is a finite extension
>
> (3) $L$ is a finite $K$-algebra (i.e. finitely generated as a $K$-vector space)

My understanding is that $(2) \iff (3)$ is immediate, as is the implication $(3) \implies (1)$.  However, the implication $(1) \implies (2)$ is non-trivial, and is a form of the weak Nullstellensatz.

Is everything I've said correct?

Comment: I would appreciate it if downvoters could explain the reason for their downvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$